# set a formula in Google Sheets using Apps Script based on a specific permutation of non-blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of resources that have four different columns of categorized tags.
I am building a search dashboard that has input options for each of these four options (fcInput = B2:B5). I want to run a script that will change the search formula (nested Filter+Search) used based on the permutation of which cells include keywords to search.

if B2 is the only cell in fcInput that is not empty, then the first formula would be returned; if B3 & B5 were not empty, then the ninth would be returned (full list below)

I am new to Apps Scripts/coding. I have tried some isBlank and multiple if, if else options. The permutations issue stalled my if/if else chain - as well as curiosity if there was a more efficient method.

**there are 16 total options for formulas:**

```
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
=FILTER(resources!C2:C,SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K),SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L),SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M),SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N))
// #16 is if all are blank, instruct user to input keywords in Input range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this function should output the formulas you want although I haven't tested the formulas themselves.

You would probably want to have it run with an onEdit() trigger.

```js
function testFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()

if(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue() != ""){
var b2 = 'SEARCH(B2,resources!K2:K)'}
else{var b2 = ""}

if(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue() != ""){
var b3 = 'SEARCH(B3,resources!L2:L)'}
else{var b3 = ""}

if(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4").getValue() != ""){
var b4 = 'SEARCH(B4,resources!M2:M)'}
else{var b4 = ""}

if(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B5").getValue() != ""){
var b5 = 'SEARCH(B5,resources!N2:N)'}
else{var b5 = ""}

var list = [b2, b3, b4, b5]

var concatenated = list.filter(Boolean).join(',');

ss.getActiveSheet().getRange([put where you want the formula here]).setFormula('=FILTER(resources!C2:C,'+ concatenated + ")")
}
```